# How do I remove the header, without removing the page number?

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\rhead{\small bla bla}
\lhead{\small bla bla}


\begin{document}

\pagestyle{fancy}
hello

\newpage

hello 2

\end{document}
```

I've tried \pagestyle{empty} in page 2, but it removes the page number. I've tried creating a new style:

```
\fancypagestyle{biblio}{%
    \lhead{}
    \rhead{}
    \cfoot{\thepage}
}
```

But the line remains there. Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you intend to have empty header and centered page number in the footer for any page, simply use the standard`\pagestyle{plain}` which does that, without the need of `fancyhdr` package.

And`\thispagestyle{plain}` does the same but only on current page.

If you really want to define it with `fancyhdr`, you can suppress the header rule by adding`\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}` to your code.

Answer (score 1):

Does this satisfy-removes the line but keeps the page numbering

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancypagestyle{firstpage}{%
    \lhead{\small bla bla}
    \rhead{\small bla bla}
}

\begin{document}
    \thispagestyle{firstpage}
    
    hello
    
    \pagestyle{plain}
    \newpage
    
    hello 2
    
\end{document}
```

**Page 1**

[image]

**Page 2**

[image]